# jQuery click event with :not

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to use the click event on some li's except those ones that have the class `.title`. This is what I've tried and can't get it to work:

```
$('.order_list li:not(.title)').click(function() {
```

According to the jQuery api `not-selector` manual, it should work... but it doesn't http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

### Update

Ok, so indeed the code it seams that was working.... it was a html issue. Thanks any way for the great answers

Comment: post some of your html aswell

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
$('.order_list li').not('.title').click(function() {
```

---

your code should work, i think markup is the culprit:

http://jsbin.com/ajegog/2/

Comment: Why are you advocating this over the solution posted in the question? They are functionally equivalent, right? Yes, your code should work, but so should the original code. It seems obvious that the problem is something else.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ycnP5/)). Are you toggling the `.title` class on and off? In that case you need to use a live delegate. In jQuery 1.7+, use `.on`:

```
$('.order_list').on('click', 'li:not(.title)', function() {
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ycnP5/1/)

Answer (score 1):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/bK3Wa/

another demo with `on` http://jsfiddle.net/bK3Wa/1/

Code is working fine,

Hope this helps and please feel free to use the fiddle to recreate :) issue I can try and help you out, cheers

**code**

```
$('.order_list li:not(.title)').click(function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
​
```

**or** with `on`

```
$('.order_list li:not(.title)').on('click', function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
​
```